# How to tell if M1 Mac has Rosetta installed?

Tags: macos, mac, apple-silicon, rosetta-2

I am trying to run only native software. So I would like to be able to monitor whether [Rosetta 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)#Rosetta_2) is available or not.

I am not asking if Rosetta 2 is *running*. I am **asking if Rosetta 2 is *present***, is capable of running.

I know I can sort on the *Kind* column of the process list seen in the [*Activity Monitor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_macOS_components#Activity_Monitor) app to find a process currently running through Rosetta 2 or running natively (“Apple”). But I want to know if the Rosetta capability in general has been installed/activated in general on my Mac, even if no app is currently running that way.

Comment: I recommend this answer as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65347893/6852081

Answer (score 35):

The Rosetta 2 installer seems to install at least three files:

```
$ lsbom -f /Library/Apple/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.RosettaUpdateAuto.bom
./Library/Apple/usr/lib/libRosettaAot.dylib 100755  0/0 322368  1011814917
./Library/Apple/usr/libexec/oah/libRosettaRuntime   100755  0/0 352176  1937385839
./Library/Apple/usr/share/rosetta/rosetta   100644  0/0 64  1875722922
```

So testing for the existance of any of those (or for content in `/usr/libexec/rosetta`) should show you whether Rosetta actually got installed.

Comment: You can also check for a package receipt:

`$ pkgutil --pkg-info com.apple.pkg.RosettaUpdateAuto`

`package-id: com.apple.pkg.RosettaUpdateAuto
version: 1.0.0.0.1.1693652110
volume: /
location: /
install-time: 1694126453`

Answer (score 25):

Another option is to check if the oahd process is running;

```
pgrep oahd
```

Internally rosetta is known as [OAH](https://eclecticlight.co/2021/01/22/running-intel-code-on-your-m1-mac-rosetta-2-and-oah/).
If it returns a process id you know rosetta is installed.
I use the following oneliner in my scripts;

```
if /usr/bin/pgrep -q oahd; then echo 'rosetta installed'; fi
```

Answer (score 14):

This simple one-liner will just print Yes or No:

```
/usr/bin/pgrep -q oahd && echo Yes || echo No
```

If you're using Jamf, this code will create an Extension Attribute and populate it accordingly:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# reports status of rosetta install

RESULT=$(/usr/bin/pgrep -q oahd && echo Yes || echo No)

echo "<result>$RESULT</result>"
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the `oahd` process won't be running until you run the first x86_64 binary after boot.

You can determine whether Rosetta is already installed or not by checking if the x86_64 binary runs without an error.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ `uname -m` != "arm64" ]] ; then
    echo "not arm64"
else
    if ! (arch -arch x86_64 uname -m > /dev/null) ; then
        echo "arm64: no Rosetta installed"
        # softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
    else
        echo "arm64: Rosetta already installed"
    fi
fi
```

The `arch` command runs the command using the specified architecture.

```
% file `which uname`
/usr/bin/uname: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e]
/usr/bin/uname (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/uname (for architecture arm64e):   Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e
% arch -arch x86_64 uname -o -m
Darwin x86_64
% arch -arch arm64 uname -o -m
Darwin arm64
```